# How to escape a single quote in a PartiQL insert statement

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, partiql

Using DynamoDB, I want to insert a record that contains a string with a single quote ('). Not sure how to escape this so it passes validation.

```
INSERT INTO "MyTable" VALUE {
  'MyAttr': 'some message containing a \' quote'
}
```

NOTE: escaping as I have above with a \ does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do so using an additional single quote:

```
INSERT INTO "MyTable" VALUE {
  'MyAttr': 'some message containing a '' quote' 
}
```